# Convert array of string to Unicode and back to ANSI in Inno Setup

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, inno-setup, pascalscript, codepages

I'm loading a Korean CP51949 (EUC-KR) encoded ANSI file into an array of strings (`LoadStringsFromFile`). My system and the intended end user systems do not have CP51949 set as a legacy non-Unicode encoding.

At the moment I have 2 problems with this:

1. Unless I run the application with Locale Emulator (which is just annoying, since the setup itself is in English only), the Korean text is displayed as gibberish.
2. `Pos` gives wrong results and `StringChange` fails completely unless I switch to `String`, do the thing, and then back to `AnsiString`.

So, I'm wondering if there's a way to convert the array to unicode, and then back before saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a file encoded in a specific Ansi encoding to Unicode `string` (UTF-16 LE), use [`MultiByteToWideChar` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar):

```pascal
function MultiByteToWideChar(
  CodePage: UINT; dwFlags: DWORD; const lpMultiByteStr: AnsiString;
    cchMultiByte: Integer; lpWideCharStr: string; cchWideChar: Integer): Integer;
  external 'MultiByteToWideChar@kernel32.dll stdcall';  

function LoadStringFromFileInCP(
  FileName: string; var S: string; CP: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Ansi: AnsiString;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Result := LoadStringFromFile(FileName, Ansi);
  if Result then
  begin
    Len := MultiByteToWideChar(CP, 0, Ansi, Length(Ansi), S, 0);
    SetLength(S, Len);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP, 0, Ansi, Length(Ansi), S, Len);
  end;
end;

function LoadStringsFromFileInCP(
  FileName: string; Strings: TStrings; CP: Integer): Boolean;
var
  S: string;
begin
  Result := LoadStringFromFileInCP(FileName, S, CP);
  if Result then Strings.Text := S;
end;
```

*(Note that I'm using [`TStrings`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TStrings) to store strings/lines collection instead of `TArrayOfString`, as `TStrings` is easier to work with)*

---

To convert Unicode `string` back to Ansi, use [`WideCharToMultiByte` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte):

```pascal
function WideCharToMultiByte(CodePage: UINT; dwFlags: DWORD;
  lpWideCharStr: string; cchWideChar: Integer; lpMultiByteStr: AnsiString;
  cchMultiByte: Integer; lpDefaultCharFake: Integer;
  lpUsedDefaultCharFake: Integer): Integer;
  external 'WideCharToMultiByte@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function SaveStringToFileInCP(FileName: string; S: string; CP: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Ansi: AnsiString;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := WideCharToMultiByte(CP, 0, S, Length(S), Ansi, 0, 0, 0);
  SetLength(Ansi, Len);
  WideCharToMultiByte(CP, 0, S, Length(S), Ansi, Len, 0, 0);
  Result := SaveStringToFile(FileName, Ansi, False);
end;

function SaveStringsToFileInCP(
  FileName: string; Strings: TStrings; CP: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SaveStringToFileInCP(FileName, Strings.Text, CP);
end;
```

---

Use the functions like:

```pascal
const
  CP_EUC_KOREAN = 51949;

var
  I: Integer;
  Strings: TStrings;
begin
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  if LoadStringsFromFileInCP('korean.txt', Strings, CP_EUC_KOREAN) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to Strings.Count - 1 do
    begin
      MsgBox(Strings[I], mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;

  SaveStringsToFileInCP('korean_out.txt', Strings, CP_EUC_KOREAN);
end;
```

---

Works correctly on my English-only system:

[image]
[image]